# Can someone suggest what pattern I used mistakenly and is it correct in this situation. Any alternative?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design, patterns-and-practices, anti-patterns

> **Client_1 uses --> IService_1 and thus Service1_impl**

```
public interface IService_1
{
    void DoTask_1();
}

public class Service1_impl : IService_1
{
    private readonly IDepService_1_v1 _depService_4;
    private readonly IDepService_2_v1 _batchdepService_4;
    private readonly IDepService_3_v1 _depService_2;
    private readonly IDepService_4_v1 _depService_3;

    public Service1_impl(
              IDepService_1_v1 depService_4, 
              IDepService_2_v1 batchdepService_4, 
              IDepService_3_v1 depService_2, 
              IDepService_4_v1 depService_3)
    {
        _depService_1 = depService_1;
        _depService_2 = depService_2;
        _depService_3 = depService_3;
        _depService_4 = depService_4;
    }
    
    public void DoTask_1()
    {
      // perform some work with help of all depServices_with_v1.
    }
}
```

> **Some new functionality added for Client_2**, so I developed like below.

> **Client_2 uses --> IService_1_v2 and thus Service_1_v2_impl **

> Service_1_v2_impl now depends on **IDepService_1_v2, IDepService_2_v2, IDepService_4_v2** which follow same patter. So *IDepService_1_v2 has base interface as IDepService_1_v1* and implementation of IDepService_1_v2 has a base class as  implementation of IDepService_1_v1 and so on.

```
public interface IService_1_v2 : IService_1
{
    void DoTask_2();
}

public class Service_1_v2_impl : Service1_impl, IService_1_v2
{
    private readonly IDepService_1_v2 _depService_1;
    private readonly IDepService_2_v2 _batchdepService_2;
    private readonly IDepService_3_v1 _depService_3;
    private readonly IDepService_4_v2 _depService_4;

    public Service1_impl(
              IDepService_1_v2 depService_1, 
              IDepService_2_v2 batchdepService_2, 
              IDepService_3_v1 depService_3, 
              IDepService_4_v2 depService_4)
    {
        _depService_1 = depService_1;
        _depService_2 = depService_2;
        _depService_3 = depService_3;
        _depService_4 = depService_4;
    }
    
    public void DoTask_2()
    {
      // perform some work with help of all_depServices_with_v1.
      base.DoTask_1();
      
      // perform some work with help of all_depServices_with_v1_OR_v2.
    }
}
```

I got review comment - this may cause interface explosion. so whenever a new requirement/ client going to be added, new set of interfaces. better patter is builder or bridge pattern.

I read through bridge pattern and to me it's still going to have interfaces explosion.

I didn't go through any pattern while writing above code, **but wondering if above code represent any pattern.**

Comment: "perform some work with help of depServices_v1." Do you not use the other services or do you have other tasks for other services ?

Comment: @JayZ I need all Dependent services to perform task. updated comment for better clarity

Comment: Single Responsibility Principle?

Comment: You don't necessarily need all these interface hierarchies. You don't have to neccesarily think of these new services as new versions of old services. This seems like a good case where you should favor composition over inheritance. Instead of inheriting, consider injecting *two or more* services as dependencies of the client. Or introduce a small object in between that delegates to these services and controls how they cooperate. If this object also implements the top level `IService` interface, than that's the Composite pattern. Try to find a balance between composition & inheritance.

Comment: I tried to start an answer but you really haven't included the details that would be needed to do so sensibly.  I think you are misusing interfaces/abstraction.  Hint: if you only have one implementation of each interface, you are doing it wrong.  What you need to explain here is the difference between these various types i.e. What makes IDepService_1* different from IDepService_2* and why you need different versions of these.